# Steps to find an orthogonal basis for a plane in $R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a linear algebra exercise where I have to find orthogonal eigenvectors to matrix A that describes mirroring in the plane $x_1-x_2+2x_3=0$

The normal $\vec{n}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\2\end{bmatrix}$ is obvious.
Now all we need are two orthogonal vectors that span the plane $x_1-x_2+2x_3=0$

I could massage the number of two vectors in the plane until they are orthogonal, but I am looking for a procedural method that hopefully would work for finding an orthogonal basis of any subspace that has one dimension less than the space it is located in e.g. a plane in $R^3$ or 3d space in $R^4$

My immediate thought is to create a matrix that rotates the z-axis to the normalised normal vector $\vec{n}$. The column vectors, of that matrix, would be the the new basis (excluding $\hat{e}_z$) since rotation is isometric and preserves the angle between vectors.

Is this an overly complicated way of doing it and is there an easier method?

Edit: The more I think about my method the more I think I first have to solve the problem just to create the rotation matrix. The easiest way for a plane in $R^3$ would probably be to take one vector in the plane and do a cross product with the normal.

Comment: If you massage up only one vector orthogonal to $n$, say, $(1,1,0)^T$ in this case, the third one can be obtained by cross product.

Comment: Yes, I realised that the more I thought about it. The whole idea behind my plan of creating a rotation matrix was based on the thought that it would be easy. But it think that was a mistake. Thank you for the response.

Comment: Nevertheless, you can use *Gram-Schmidt* procedure. For that you need to extend $n$ by two other vectors to a basis, then the procedure creates an orthogonal/orthonormal basis.

Comment: You can also pick two arbitrary vectors generating the plane and use Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting Gram-Schmidt. Now I have a thread to start pulling at.

Comment: Nevertheless, you can always come up with one easily calculated orthogonal. In a 3d problem, this together with cross product is a full algorithm. Say, $n$ contains a zero coordinate, then the corresponding standard basis vector is just fine. Otherwise pick, say, the two smallest absolute value coordinates, say $n_i$ and $n_j$, then put $-n_j$ in the $i$th coordinate, $n_i$ in the $j$th coordinate and $0$ elsewhere.